# What does "dead end" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Pere Tanguy says to Armand about Vincent:

> Pere Tanguy: He joined his uncle's art dealership and was thrown out
> in disgrace. He tried for his father's profession, the church, but the
> pastor exams were too hard for him, so he took a job as a lowly
> missionary. He managed to get sacked even from that. Yet another **dead
> end**.

What does "dead end" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dead end" here refers to a situation Vincent is in where there are no prospects of any progress.

Answer (score 0):

A [dead end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_end_(street)) is a place where a road abruptly ends.

By analogy, Vincent has tried taking an art-dealer's career path, and a clergyman's career path, but in both situations failed in such a way that he can proceed no further down either path (as if each were now a dead-end street to him).